# Adding simple modal library to rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to add [Simple modal](http://simplemodal.plasm.it/) javascript library to my rails app

On webpage all js files are loaded successfully

```
<script src="/assets/simple-modal/mootools-core-1.3.1.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/simple-modal/mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/simple-modal/simple-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried to add event like this in coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#batch a.accept").live 'click', ->
    SM = new SimpleModal(btn_ok: "Alert button")
    SM.show
      title: "Title"
      contents: "Your message..."
```

With this code in firebug console i got

```
TypeError: $("simple-modal").getElement is not a function
```

When i try to add event with javascript like in manual:

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(e){
/* Alert */
$("#batch a.accept").addEvent("click", function(e){
  e.stop();
  var SM = new SimpleModal({"btn_ok":"Alert button"});
      SM.show({
        "title":"Alert Modal Title",
        "contents":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
      });
});
});
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: $("#batch a.accept").addEvent is not a function
```

What can i do?

Comment: can you supply jsfiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add jquery to the top of the scripts list

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/simple-modal/mootools-core-1.3.1.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/simple-modal/mootools-more-1.3.1.1.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/simple-modal/simple-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have jquery at the top of the scripts list.